# I want to create a timer in python, which runs while program is running and gives a message when timer completes

Tags: python

I want to a timer inside my python program, which keeps running while the program is running and once timer is over, it displays a message or performs an action like breaking a loop or continuing the loop.

Comment: You can set an alarm and do something in the callback... https://medium.com/@chamilad/timing-out-of-long-running-methods-in-python-818b3582eed6

Comment: With all due respect, the supposedly answer/solution `How can I time a code segment for testing performance with Pythons timeit?` is not what Walnut street is asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use threads to execute a timer while the program is running. Here is a explanation to threads: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
import time
from random import random

timer = int(input("Enter time: "))
while True:
    text = random.randint(1, 10)
    time.sleep(timer)
    break
print(text)
```

You can always change what you wanna do inside the while loop.

Hope it worked!!